# integrate four functions into single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four counter in a single page I have called separate function for each function.I need to integrate all function into single function.

```js
var tt1 = setInterval(function() {
  startTimee()
}, 50);
var counter1 = 1;

function startTimee() {
  if (counter1 == 10) {
    clearInterval(tt1);
  } else {
    counter1++;
  }
  document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML = counter1;

}
var tt = setInterval(function() {
  startTime()
}, 5);
var counter = 1;

function startTime() {
  if (counter == 600) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
  document.getElementById('counter2').innerHTML = counter;
}
var tt2 = setInterval(function() {
  startTime2()
}, 50);
var counter2 = 1;

function startTime2() {
  if (counter2 == 30) {
    clearInterval(tt2);
  } else {
    counter2++;
  }
  document.getElementById('count3').innerHTML = counter2;
}
var tt3 = setInterval(function() {
  startTime3()
}, 50);
var counter3 = 1;

function startTime3() {
  if (counter3 == 6) {
    clearInterval(tt3);
  } else {
    counter3++;
  }
  document.getElementById('counter4').innerHTML = counter3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter1">10</div>
<div id="counter2">600</div>
<div id="counter3">30</div>
<div id="counter4">6</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make them all run under the same `setTimeout` code?

Comment: yeah need to run under same setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
var time = 1, interval = setInterval(tick, 50);

function tick()
{
  if (time <= 10)
    document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML = time;

  if (time <= 600)
    document.getElementById('counter2').innerHTML = time;

  if (time <= 30)
    document.getElementById('counter3').innerHTML = time;

  if (time <= 6)
    document.getElementById('counter4').innerHTML = time;     

  if (++time > 600) 
    clearInterval(interval); 
}
```

```html
<p id="counter1"></p>
<p id="counter2"></p>
<p id="counter3"></p>
<p id="counter4"></p>
```

It is far not the most optimal code, but it is just an example for you to get the main principle.

Comment: `return clearInterval(...)` is kind of an odd way to do it - it implies that there is a meaningful value being returned. If you moved that `if` statement to the end of the function you wouldn't need a `return` statement at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn The usage of `return` is different in Javascript to other, strongly-typed languages and using `return clearInterval(interval);` is perfectly clear to any reader paying attention.  It is common for return values to be unused / irrelevant in this language.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches that you could take in doing this, depending on where values come from.

The first option is to create an object that holds the `span`'s `id` and the max value to count to.

```js
var countCeiling = {
  counter1: {
    end: 10
  },
  counter2: {
    end: 600,
    start: 0
  },
  counter3: {
    end: 30,
    start: 0
  },
  counter4: {
    end: 6,
    start: 0
  }
};

var timerID = setInterval(function() {
  var stopTimer = true;

  for (var id in countCeiling) {
    var data = countCeiling[id];
    var span = document.getElementById(id);

    var val = data.current || data.start || 0;

    data.current = val + 1;

    if (val <= data.end) {
      span.innerHTML = val;
      stopTimer = false;
    }

  }

  if (stopTimer) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter1">10</div>
<div id="counter2">600</div>
<div id="counter3">30</div>
<div id="counter4">6</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to actually test `stopTimer`, but I like the iterative approach. If you said `var val = data.current || data.start || 0;` you could make the `start` property optional for the `counterX` objects.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good points, thanks.  Fixed.  I was fighting back the urge to make `current` one of the properties in that configuration array ... too much `TypeScript` lately for me ;)